# Error: Unknown symbols found":" Unknown property type filter, even when everything seems working

Tags: css, netbeans, filter

In my CSS file, i have added a filter as follows:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00a9ed', endColorstr='#0003c4',GradientType=1 );
```

Although my gradient works as expected, NetBeans continues to report two errors:

1. Unknown symbols found: ":" (it is highlighting the : next to progid)
2. Unknown property filter

Should I be concerned with this error when the gradient runs properly? Any thoughts on how can I clear this?

Comment: that only tells you that NetBeans considers IE own css specs as not valid. No reason to freak out.

Comment: My NetBeans doesn't error with it at all - what version are you on?

Comment: I am running NetBeans version 6.8

Answer (score 0):

`filter` is non-standard property only for IE, so I guess NetBeans is picking on that wrong syntax and firing an error.

Maybe you just need to update your NetBeans as it is a fixed bug:

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=168406